# apply font-weight bold to the option in the select Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<style type = "text/css">
.myClass{
  font-weight: bold ;
  font-size: 8pt;
  color:red;  
}
</style>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#select1 > option[data-status=YES]").addClass("myClass");      
});
```

It is not working in  IE 6.0 and  IE 8.0 and It is working fine in Mozilla. How do I apply `font-weight: bold` to the `option` in the `select` element that has the `data-status`  as "`YES`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in IE6. Styling form elements is extremely limited even in modern browsers.

You would have to use a JavaScript-based `select` alternative like [this one.](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)